# how do I check image size in android while uploading from phone gallery?

Tags: android

i want to check image size once user select an image from gallery.Because big size images are not allowed in my app. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: what it returns ? i mean in MB or in Kb ?

Comment: please read the documentation (which is rather explicit on this matter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help to you....

```
  File Img = new File(selectedImage.getPath());
  int length = Img.length();
```

This returns length in Bytes.

Comment: in my case, selectedImage.getPath() returns the path but .length() returns 0 hence I cannot get the size.